# Webapp based Android keyboard

Tags: android, gwt, web-applications, cordova, android-input-method

I am programming an Android keyboard. Right now I reached the point where I have to rewrite the KeyboardView and I'm asking myself why not to switch to an Webapp instead of a native Android app. Thereby I could later easily deploy the application for other platforms whithout the need of rewriting.

My approach would be to use the Android App as an container for my web app probaply in combination with GWT. I am also considering using PhoneGap.

The problem is that so far I haven't found anything about people using webapps for an InputMethod. Now I'm wondering if it's reasonable or even possible to use webapps for this task or if they are only suitable for normal activities.

Has anyone tried doing this before or some hints why or why not it is possible?